# Unable to create custom BlockEmbed using Quill 2.0-dev3

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5, quill, parchment

We have been using Quill 1.3.7 for a while. I had some custom embed blots written that were working without issue. We then upgraded to 2.0.0-dev3 to gain new functionality and this has broken our custom blots. I receive the following error when I select the option in the toolbar:

`Class constructor BlockEmbed cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Here's some of what I've tried:

```
import Quill from "quill";

class PageBreak extends Quill.import("blots/block/embed") ...
class PageBreak extends Quill.import("blots/embed") ...
class PageBreak extends Quill.import("parchment").EmbedBlot ...
class PageBreak extends Quill.import("parchment").Embed ...
```

These all resulted in the above listed error.

Additionally, I've gone down the route of using Parchment directly with different errors (usually Parchment being undefined):

```
import Parchment from "parchment";

class PageBreak extends Parchment.Embed ...
class PageBreak extends Parchment.EmbedBlot ...
```

I'm using the Quill.insertEmbed() function to accomplish this. I've also attempted creating a Delta and updating the document.

An example with our custom PageBreak blot can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-flower-8kuy2?file=/src/PageBreak.ts

We are targeting es5.